# Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.moveTo

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I simply create a function which moving the specified file to an folder from the existing folder. But it return an Exception when i run it:
"Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.moveTo."

May I know what is the problem in my coding?

```
function movtofldr() {DriveApp.getFileById('thisFileID').moveTo('destinationFolderID');}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination) for `moveTo()`. It indicates that the argument is a `Folder`, therefore you need to prepend the following variable declaration to make it work:

```
function movtofldr(){ 
  const targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("destinationFolderID")
  DriveApp.getFileById('thisFileID').moveTo(targetFolder);
}
```

Comment: Great, then please mark it as resolved.