# Move a file per GScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I try to move a file from my root-folder into a defined folder. But my script send me the fautl: "Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.moveTo." - but why?

Does anyone has a tip for me?

```js
function myMoveFile() {
  var myFolderID = DriveApp.searchFolders("Title Contains 'Final_Folder'").next().getId();

  var myNewDoc = DocumentApp.create("Doc per Script");
  var myFileID = myNewDoc.getId();  
  DocumentApp.openById(myFileID).getBody().appendParagraph("TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT");
  
  Logger.log(myFolderID);

  DriveApp.getFileById(myFileID).moveTo(myFolderID);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.moveTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69605561/exception-the-parameters-string-dont-match-the-method-signature-for-driveapp)

Answer (score 1):

`destination` of `moveTo(destination)` is the folder object which is not the folder ID. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. So how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myMoveFile() {
  var myFolder = DriveApp.searchFolders("Title Contains 'Final_Folder'").next();

  var myNewDoc = DocumentApp.create("Doc per Script");
  var myFileID = myNewDoc.getId();  
  DocumentApp.openById(myFileID).getBody().appendParagraph("TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT");
  
  Logger.log(myFolder.getId());

  DriveApp.getFileById(myFileID).moveTo(myFolder);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination)

### Added:

About the following 2nd question,

> My intention is to create a file via GScript and then move it to a defined folder (e.g. "Final_Folder"). There are 2 folders with the same name that I want to move I avoid that the file is moved to the wrong folder.

In this case, as a workaround, how about using the star? At Google Drive, a star can be added to the files and folders. In your situation, when the same folders are existing and you want to move the file to one of those folders, please add a star to the specific folder you want to use. I thought that this might be a workaround for identifying the specific folder from the same folder name.

#### Sample script:

Before you run this script, please add a star to the folder you want to use. And, run this script. By this, the file is moved to the starred folder. By this, you can use the specific folder from the same folder names.

```js
function myMoveFile() {
  var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders("Title Contains 'Final_Folder'");
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var myFolder = folders.next();
    if (myFolder.isStarred()) {
      var myNewDoc = DocumentApp.create("Doc per Script");
      var myFileID = myNewDoc.getId();
      DocumentApp.openById(myFileID).getBody().appendParagraph("TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT");

      Logger.log(myFolder.getId());

      DriveApp.getFileById(myFileID).moveTo(myFolder);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks - Now it works fine.
What should I do if there are several folders with the same name?

Comment: @J. Doe Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `What should I do if there are several folders with the same name?`, in that case, what will you do? You want to move the file of the specific folder from the same folders? If it's so, how about using the folder ID? The folder ID is the unique value. So even when there are several same folder names, you can move the file to the specific folder. If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: My intention is to create a file via GScript and then move it to a defined folder (e.g. "Final_Folder"). There are 2 folders with the same name that I want to move I avoid that the file is moved to the wrong folder.

Comment: @J. Doe Thank you for replying. In that case, how about using the folder ID as I have already mentioned in my previous comment? If you don't want to use the folder ID, I apologize for this. At that time, for example, do you use the created time of each folder for identifying the folder you want to use? I deeply apologize that I cannot immediately understand what you want to do. This is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for this.

Comment: Hello, please do not say sorry - I am happy when you send me a solution for my problem. But this with the date is a good idea. Thanks

Comment: @J. Doe Thank you for replying. As a workaround, I proposed to use a star to the folder. I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hello, you workaround-script looks perfect. It is nearly was I mean. To avoid scrolling through the hit list the search can be made more precise: "type:folder title:Final_Folder is:starred".

Comment: @J. Doe Thank you for replying. I'm glad your both 1st and 2nd questions were resolved.